# Magento 1.9.3.8 Full https causes double / ending

Tags: magento-1.9, url, https, base-url

I made my entire site https by changing the **unsecure_url** to https rather than http. Then in my **.htaccess** I added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.MYSITE\.co.uk 
RewriteRule (.*)http://www.MYSITE.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I'm faced this the weird issue of having a double trailing slash the end of my URL's when I visit my site via:

1. `http://www.mysite.co.uk`
2. `mysite.co.uk`
3. `https://mysite.co.uk`

However, I am lost as to why the double trailing slashes is occurring, would anyone be able to kindly help myself?  Auto-redirect to Base URL config is also set to:

> YES ("301 moved permanently")

Check the Network tab in Firefox I can see that when accessing the site as `https://mysite.co.uk` it will redirect to `http://www.mysite.co.uk` then `https://www.mysite.co.uk`. However, `www.mysite.co.uk` will correctly direct to `https:www.mysite.co.uk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the issue of double redirects and double forward slashes with the following:

```
############################################
## 301 redirect for http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

############################################
##SETTING THE PREFERENCE TO BE WWW##

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Instead of relying on the **HTTP_HOST**, which is obtained from the HTTP request header and this is what the client actually used as "target host" of the request.

I implicitly set in the http to https rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to redirect all http traffic to their corresponding https pages, same as yours except the trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have amended my http to https without the trailing slash, I think the issue is the non-www to www